# webdriver (c#) - looping page refresh until an elements style doesn't exist

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm struggling a little with a method I need.  Here is what I want to do:

1. I want to load a webpage
2. On that webpage, I want to wait until a specific element and it's style attribute contains "hidden: true;".  When this style is present, the page has been fully loaded so I can continue my tests
3. I need to continue refreshing the webpage until the above condition is true - Please assume I need to keep refreshing.  I know it seems stupid.

Here is what I'm trying

**Step 1:**

Navigating to a webpage (writing code from memory):

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://example.com");
```

**Step 2:**

Find the style from the specific element (Writing code from memory)

```
Iwebelement MyElement = driver.findElement(By.id("example"));
Iwebelement MyElementStyle = MyElement.GetAttribute("style");
```

**Step 3:**

If the element has a style of "hidden: true;" on page load then do nothing else perform a page refresh until the element doesn't contain a style of "hidden: true;" (Writing code from memory)

```
if(MyElementStyle.Contains("hidden: true;"))

{
  //  do nothing 
}

else
{
      driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://example.com");
}
```

This appears to be working but the above code will only refresh the page one time so I need to loop rather than use an if statement.

Would anyone be able to offer a few pointers or suggest a better way of approaching this?

Comment: This is going to be incredibly slow and inefficient especially so in Selenium Grid. Why the need for refreshing? Ideally, your application would have a stable way of identifying "is this page ready for me to use".

Comment: The AUT currently has a known issue in that sometimes it will load and other times it will not.  I know it's not ideal and the test itself isn't ideal but we need to stick with doing the refresh for now.  Appreciate your input as always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure what language binding you are using but looks like a mixture of C# and java and if that's the real test code it will not work.

Use `do while` loop to do a post check and check if the attribute has expected value or not.

```
IWebElement MyElement = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("example"));
string MyElementStyle = MyElement.GetAttribute("style");

do
{
   Driver.Navigate().Refresh();

} while (MyElementStyle.Contains("hidden: true;"));
```